# Can jQuery run a loop?

Tags: jquery, loops

I am using jQuery to allow my users to quickly go through their profiles. They have an inbox on their profiles and I am letting them delete past messages using jQuery. The problem is that each time the page is loaded there will be a different number of emails. How can I tell jQuery to manage the function for mail1 and mail2 and mail 3 etc but only if they exists.

Below you will see the jquery I am running for each but there needs to be a loop of some kind.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#del1").click(function() {
    $(".mail1").fadeOut();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#del2").click(function() {
    $(".mail2").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by `loop` i see nothing to loop on.

Comment: If the element in question that you're interacting with doesn't exist, jQuery will usually fail silently, so usually there's no need to check first. I also think you need to clarify your question, where do loops come in to this?

Comment: It seems @Michael wants to loop over all his `del` elements and bind a click event to them, when in fact what he should be doing is binding a single click event to all the relevant elements, and then deciding what to hide based on the ID of the element that was clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make your elements and code more generic.  For instance, give all delete links the same class, lets say `deleteButton` and all mails the same class, say `mail`.

Then use their proximity to deal with them.  Maybe something like this:

```
$(".deleteButton").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find(".mail").fadeOut();
});
```

**This assumes that the button and the mail share a common parent**, but even if they don't, something similar can be done.

Comment: @kingjiv I don't think "this" should be in quotes should it?

Comment: @kasdegar nope, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

Give each delete button a common class, and a `data-id` attribute.  You can bind the click event to each del button, then delete the corresponding mail element.

```
$(".del").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $(".mail" + id).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: That's the same as `$(".mail").fadeOut()` why loop?  Plus he only wants to hide the mail items relating to the clicked delete button.

Comment: I dont think this deserved a downvote. It's pretty much correct except without a nice descriptive explanation.

Comment: The loop described I think is he thinks he should loop and have `#del1`, `#del2`, etc. in a loop until one of them doesn't exist.  Just a bad idea.

Comment: This isn't what the user should be doing.

Comment: See the edit.  I think this solves the problem of looping over delete buttons and deleting the corresponding mail element, instead of looping over each mail element.

Comment: Closer but I think you wanted to give each `.del` a click not an `each`.

Comment: any attribute prefixed with `data-` is ignored by the browser, and can be used by script.

Comment: @kingjiv I fixed it to use click.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

```
$("[id^='del']").each(function(){
 $(this).click(function(){
  $('.mail'+(/\d+/).exec($(this).attr("id"))).fadeOut();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Bind a click event to all of the del
   elements.
2. When they are clicked, get the ID
   and use it to get the name of the
   relevant class to be hidden.
3. Use that class name to do the
   `fadeOut()`

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=del]").each(function(){
    var e=$(this),m = e.attr('id').match(/^del(\d+)$/);
    if( m ){
      e.click(function(){$('#.mail'+m[1]).fadeOut();});
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("#del1").length){
      $("#del1").click(function() {
        $(".mail1").fadeOut();
      });
    }
    if($("#del2").length){
      $("#del2").click(function() {
        $(".mail2").fadeOut();
      });
    }
    ....
});
```

Comment: just the if($("*")){ and  the ... will do it?

Comment: I don't think there are a fixed number of `#del` elements.  I think he's saying they are dynamically created and he doesn't know how many he has.

Answer (score -1):

Jquery allows you to select with 'startswith' you could also use jquery's regex selector but I think this gets you close:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('*[id^="del"]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('[class^="mail"]').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

This assumes that class="mail..." is an ancestor at some point of id="del..."

Since we don't know your exact HTML I like closest instead of parent since parent assumes that del is one layer directly inside of mail.

Comment: As far as I can tell this would hide all `mail` elements when any `del` elements are clicked. The OP wants to hide the corresponding `mail` element.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  Edited/corrected to put the fadeOut into context

Comment: `this` in that context is the delete button, the mail is not contained within the delete button so find won't find anything.

Comment: Well you're right in one respect, I can't assume that the mail is in the context of the "del" element.  But in the same respect you can't assume that it isn't.  I guess I'm pointing out that the question doesn't specify the html involved.  We don't even know if it is a button.

Comment: as I was writing a example to make my case I realized that it's unlikely that "mail" would be a child of "del" and more than likely that its the other way around.  I've edited my answer to reflect that assumption.

Comment: This answer has been edited please adjust your down vote accordingly.  If there's still something you don't like then let me know and I'll fix it.